# Explanations of the #select in select angular

Tags: angular

```
                  <select (change)="changeNatureImpot(id, 'natureImpotId', selectNatureImpot.value)"
                        #selectNatureImpot class="form-control" >
                        <option [ngValue]="null"></option> 
                        <option [ngValue]="tni1130Option.codeNatImp" *ngFor="let tni1130Option of tni1130s">
                            {{tni1130Option.libelleNatImp}}-{{tni1130Option.codeNatImp}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

I wanted to bind the value tni1130option.codeNatImp automatically when I arrive in the page but It refuses to work I don't understand what is making that .Could somebody explain me ?

Comment: Please add your ts file to give you a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***#selectNatureImpot*** permit to take the value of the selected option to send it in the function called in the change event so there is no link with binding the tni1130option.codeNatImp to option .

The solution here was that : PASSING THE VALUE OF THE tni1130Option.libelleNatImp in the form by taking it on NgOnInit with a this.activate.route